# How add Ckeditor on EntityType field

Tags: 8, entities

I make a custom Entity content module, and for a field i want ckEditor.

Here my code for this field :

```
$fields['description'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string_long')
    ->setLabel(t('Description'))
    ->setRequired(true)
    ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
        'label' => 'above',
        'type' => 'string_textarea',
        'weight' => -4,

    ))
    ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
        'type' => 'string_textarea',
        'weight' => -4,
        'settings' => array(
            'placeholder' => 'Description de votre annonce',
        ),
    ))
    ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE)
    ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);
```

> Type : string_textarea

How can i tell Drupal 8 to get the widget for textarea basic html mode ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 4 different field types that contain a text

- string
- string_long
- text
- text_long

What long means should be obvious, the difference between string and text is that text has a format (like full_html or basic_html) while string is always plain text.

You are currently using string_long, it doesn't make sense to show a wyswiwyg editor for that, since it would always escape all HTML. Use text_long instead.

Comment: Thank you, i was searching for this type text_long.... i don't find any doc on where are all the type.

Comment: Is it possible to also select the default format? Can't really find anything about this.

Answer (score 0):

Piggybacking on @Berdir's answer, add this to your settings array:

`'allowed_formats' => ['ckeditor' => TRUE]`